# javascript - store precreated objects (o1, o2, o3 ..) in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have several objects created .. p0, p1, p2, ... p. where max 'n' is known.  The p? objects have customized methods in them (eg., startp() ).

I would like to push them into an array (lets call it 'A').  That way, given some index i, I want to call some method like:  A[i].startp().  My javascript code:

```
A = [];
for (var i=0; i<=n; i++){
    A.push( eval('p'+i) );
}
```

I get errors like "ReferenceError: p0 is not defined".

Thanks.

Comment: Fix the code so they are created in an array in the first place instead of in a bunch of variables with similar names.

Comment: Please post the code where you create these objects. And don't use `eval()`... in 99% of the cases there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
var p0 = { x: "foo" };
var p1 = { x: "bar" };
```

etc, just do this:

```
var A = [
  { x: "foo" },
  { x: "bar" }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally Id just go with the answer Pointy gave, but depending on where p? is declared (think they call that scope) you could do something like this to avoid eval....

```
var A = [];
for (var i=0; i<=n; i++){
    A.push(window['p'+i]);
}
```

...replace window with what works ;)...hard to give you an exact answer without seeing more code.

Comment: The thing is that these p? objects are created at random in no specific order in some modules that are imported before the module creating the A[] array. Object creation sequence might be something like: p1, p3, p0, p2 .. .  I can't just push them into some array as soon as these p? create themselves since I want them to be in the right sequence (even assuming that A[] existed before the p? objects were created).